# Getting a set with unique column values from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unique, distinct

Say that I have a set with columns like this

```
user_id | username | updated_at | data...
```

`user_id` and `username` are not unique in the set, so you can have something like this

```
user_id | username | updated_at | data...
------------------------------------------
   1    |   test   |  140****** | ...  
   4    |   test2  |  140****** | ...  
   1    |   test   |  139****** | ...  
   7    |   meh    |  140****** | ...
```

But I would like to remove the duplicate occurrences; I tried `GROUP BY` but it gives me something unexpected as a lot of items are getting removed (I guess they appears later in the set as the query has a `LIMIT` in it).

Comment: What duplicates do you want to remove? Where all columns are the same or just the user_id and username? If just user_id and username do you want to return values for the other columns and if so which values? ie, would you want the first or last updated_at?

Comment: @Kickstart just the last updated_at if user_id is duplicated (username is dependent on user_id, so it's a consequence)

Comment: In which case the solution by Tata below should give you the data you want (although you do not need the data column so can remove the GROUP_CONCAT() of that).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select all the data - first of all u should decide how to get the updated_at and data columns.

In case you want to have the data concatenated and you want to have the latest updated_at you should do

```
SELECT user_id, username, max(updated_at), group_concat(data separator ',')
FROM table_name
GROUP BY user_id, username
ORDER BY user_id, username
LIMIT X
```

in that case your data will be ordered by user_id, and username

Note: 
it is not clear from your question if you want to remove the data from the table itself or only from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select distinct user_id, username
from table t;
```